# Problems to build duktape using low_memory.yaml and pointer compression options

Tags: duktape

I'm trying to build duktape using the low_memory.yaml profile, and enabling the pointer compression options.  Specifically, I uncommented the following lines:

```
DUK_USE_STRTAB_PTRCOMP: true  # sometimes useful with pointer compression
DUK_USE_REFCOUNT16: true
DUK_USE_REFCOUNT32: false
DUK_USE_STRHASH16: true
DUK_USE_STRLEN16: true
DUK_USE_BUFLEN16: true
DUK_USE_OBJSIZES16: true
DUK_USE_HSTRING_CLEN: false
DUK_USE_HSTRING_LAZY_CLEN: false
DUK_USE_HOBJECT_HASH_PART: false
DUK_USE_HEAPPTR16
DUK_USE_HEAPPTR_DEC16
DUK_USE_HEAPPTR_ENC16
```

The remaining lines are left untouched.  When I use the python utility like this:

```
python  tools/configure.py --output-directory ~/duktape-src/low_mem_t --option-file config/examples/low_memory_t1.yaml
```

I got a lot of exceptions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/duktape-2.2.1/tools/genconfig.py", line 1522, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pi/duktape-2.2.1/tools/genconfig.py", line 1519, in main
    genconfig(opts, args)
  File "/home/pi/duktape-2.2.1/tools/genconfig.py", line 1498, in genconfig
    result, active_opts = generate_duk_config_header(opts, meta_dir)
  File "/home/pi/duktape-2.2.1/tools/genconfig.py", line 970, in generate_duk_config_header
    forced_opts = get_forced_options(opts)
  File "/home/pi/duktape-2.2.1/tools/genconfig.py", line 795, in get_forced_options
    doc = yaml.load(StringIO(val))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 71, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 115, in check_token
    while self.need_more_tokens():
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 149, in need_more_tokens
    self.stale_possible_simple_keys()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 289, in stale_possible_simple_keys
    "could not find expected ':'", self.get_mark())
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
  in "<file>", line 85, column 1
could not find expected ':'
  in "<file>", line 86, column 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/configure.py", line 993, in <module>
    main()
  File "tools/configure.py", line 605, in main
    exec_print_stdout(cmd)
  File "tools/configure.py", line 60, in exec_print_stdout
    ret = exec_get_stdout(cmd, input=input, print_stdout=True)
  File "tools/configure.py", line 51, in exec_get_stdout
    raise Exception('command failed, return code %d: %r' % (proc.returncode, cmd))
Exception: command failed, return code 1: ['/usr/bin/python', '/home/pi/duktape-2.2.1/tools/genconfig.py', '--output', '/tmp/tmp-duk-prepare-Xu0Jx4/duk_config.h.tmp', '--output-active-options', '/tmp/tmp-duk-prepare-Xu0Jx4/duk_config_active_options.json', '--git-commit', 'external', '--git-describe', 'external', '--git-branch', 'external', '--used-stridx-metadata', '/tmp/tmp-duk-prepare-Xu0Jx4/duk_used_stridx_bidx_defs.json.tmp', '--metadata', '/home/pi/duktape-2.2.1/config', '--option-file', '/tmp/tmp-duk-prepare-Xu0Jx4/genconfig0.yaml', 'duk-config-header']
```

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate that the config file cannot be parsed as a YAML file -- could you check that the commenting out respects YAML syntax?